# Printing odd numbered characters in a string without string slicing?

Tags: python, string, loops, character

I'm currently doing a project for my university, and one of the assignments was to get python to only print the odd characters in a string, when I looked this up all I could find were string slicing solutions which I was told not to use to complete this task. I was also told to use a loop for this as well. Please help, thank you in advance.
Here is my code so far, it prints the string in each individual character using a for loop, and I need to modify it so that it prints the odd characters.

```
i = input("Please insert characters: ")
for character in i:
    print(character)
```

Comment: We can't help without you showing us your code

Comment: For those looking for the right way, use string slicing like this:  '38566593'[0::2]  for odds , '38566593'[-2::-2] for evens.  First denotes where to start from, second is step.

Answer (score 1):

Please follow this code to print odd numbered characters

```
#Read Input String 
i = input("Please insert characters: ")
#Index through the entire string
for index in range(len(i)):
    #Check if odd 
    if(index % 2 != 0):
        #print odd characters
        print(i[index])
```

Answer (score 0):

I think more information would be helpful to answer this question. It is not clear to me whether the string only contains numbers. Anyway, maybe this answers your question.

```
string = '38566593'

for num in string:
    if int(num) % 2 == 1:
        print(num)
```

To extend on Kyrubas's answer, you could use-

```
string = '38566593'

for i, char in enumerate(string):
    if i % 2 == 1:
        print(char)
```

Comment: Well basically to my knowledge, the functionality of the program would be letting an individual enter a string, then python would print out every other letter of the string.  I'm sorry if my wording for the question was wrong I meant to say "odd numbered characters" not odd characters in general.

Comment: Oh okay, then the second answer is the one you want. Just make string = input("Enter a string: ") and that should work.

Comment: Thank you, I used the code and its working the way I was thinking of in my head!

Comment: No problem. Just so you know,  for i, char in enumerate(string) gets the index and element for each character of the string. This approach is preferred over the use of an integer counter. Also, feel free to indicate if my reply was useful :) As a new user, I need some extra cred to unlock some capabilities.....

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

```
a= 'this is my code'
count = 1
for each in list(a):
    if count % 2 != 0:
        print(each)
        count+=1
    else:
        count+=1
```

Comment: Thank you very much!  This might be what I'm looking for since I've seen the if and else loop in my university class!  I'm so sorry to ask, but I wasn't able to make it to some of my classes so I don't really understand how this loop works, would it be too much to ask for an explanation of how this code works so that I'll be able to replicate it in the future instead of feeling like I'm just mooching off you guys?

Comment: The `for` loop takes each element of a list or range and does what it is encompassing.

I should note that `list(a)` is rather unnecessary as Python automatically sees strings as list. i.e.

the `if` statement uses modulus arithmetic meaning it divides the current `count` by 2 and returns the remainder. In this case if the remainder is not equal to (`!=`)  the continue on to the if statement, otherwise got to `else`.

The `if` statement first prints the current iteration of the `for` loop, then increments the variable `count` by 1 as indicated by the `+=`.

Answer (score 0):

person = raw_input("Enter your name: ")
a = 1
print"hello " , person
print "total : " , len(person)
for each in list (person):
    if a % 2 ==0:
        print "even chars : " , (each)
        a+=1
    else:
        a+=1

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please format your code and provide some context to it. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

```
s = raw_input()
even_string=''
odd_string=''
for index in range(len(s)):
    if index % 2 != 0:
        odd_string = odd_string+s[index]
    else:
        even_string = even_string+ (s[index])
print even_string,odd_string
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. For even index start you can use `range(0, len(s), 2)`.

```py
s = input()
res = ''
for i in range(1,len(s),2):
    res +=s[i]
print(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

When we want to split a string, we can use the syntax:

```
str[beg:end:jump]
```

When we put just one number, this number indicates the index.
When we put just two numbers, the first indicates the first character (included) and the second, the last character (excluded) of the substring

You can just read the string and print it like this:

```
i = input("Please insert characters: ")
print(i[::2])
```

When you put `str[::]` the return is all the string (from `0` to `len(str)`), the last number means the jump you want to take, that meaning that you will print the characters 0, 2, 4, etc

Answer (score 0):

You can use gapped index calling. `s[start:end:gap]`

```
s = 'abcdefgh'
print(s[::2])
# 'aceg'
```

returning the characters with indexes 0, 2, 4, and 6. It starts from position 0 to the end and continues with a gap of 2.

```
print(s[1::2])
# 'bdfh'
```

Returning the characters with indexes 1, 3, 5, and 7. It starts from position 1 and goes with a gap of 2.